# WPF Button with Rectangle and OpacityMask

Tags: c#, wpf, opacitymask

I would like to make an UI like Facebook navigation bar.
My idea was to make the Background of the Button to Transparent and put an icon on it as an OpacityMask of a Rectangle and change the Fill of it. I've got so confused creating the Style.

Here's the Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Button btn = new Button
    {
        Name = ("btnUi" + i).ToString(),
        Width = 42,
        Height = 42,
        Content = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = Brushes.DarkBlue,
            OpacityMask = new ImageBrush
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\images\ui_0" + (i + 1).ToString() + ".png"))
            },
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Width = 32,
            Height = 32
        },               
        Style = this.FindResource("uiStyle01") as Style
    };
    if (i == 0) btn.IsEnabled = false;
    btn.Click += btnUi_Click;
    uiPanel.Children.Add(btn);
}
```

And the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="uiStyle01">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" Fill="MidnightBlue">
                    </Rectangle>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
    </Style> 
</Application.Resources>
```

I appriciate any idea to make it easier too.

[facebook_sample_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nlij.png)

Comment: Nice story. But what is your question? ("I would like to" is not a question.)

Comment: What is not working as expected?

Comment: How to make the Style (if it's needed) or how to do it in general? With this xaml the whole button is filled and the image is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

"Template" in Style will overwrite the Image you are adding  as Content from c#

Template is simply add content to Button.

Simple solution

Remove "Template" from the style in xaml.

Use below

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="uiStyle01">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
             </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This will simply update the background of button and Keep the image as it is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it's not the way I'd like to do it. The Image Color should change and the Background needs to be transparent in every case. Is there a way to change the Fill of the Rectangle while keeping the ImageSource of it's OpacityMask (to change the color of the image)?

Comment: The best way I would suggest is use 2 images for enabled and disabled condition